# Scala Spark setting schema duplicates columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have an issue when specifying the schema of my dataframe. Without setting the schema, printschema() produces:

```
root
 |-- Store: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- IsHoliday: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Dept: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Weekly_Sales: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Temperature: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Fuel_Price: string (nullable = true)
 |-- MarkDown1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- MarkDown2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- MarkDown3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- MarkDown4: string (nullable = true)
 |-- MarkDown5: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CPI: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Unemployment: string (nullable = true)
```

However, when i specify the schema with .schema(schema)

```
val dfr = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").schema(schema)
```

My printschema() produces:

```
root
 |-- Store: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Date: date (nullable = true)
 |-- IsHoliday: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- Dept: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Weekly_Sales: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Temperature: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Fuel_Price: double (nullable = true)
 |-- MarkDown1: double (nullable = true)
 |-- MarkDown2: double (nullable = true)
 |-- MarkDown3: double (nullable = true)
 |-- MarkDown4: double (nullable = true)
 |-- MarkDown5: double (nullable = true)
 |-- CPI: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Unemployment: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Dept: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Weekly_Sales: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Temperature: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Fuel_Price: double (nullable = true)
 |-- MarkDown1: double (nullable = true)
 |-- MarkDown2: double (nullable = true)
 |-- MarkDown3: double (nullable = true)
 |-- MarkDown4: double (nullable = true)
 |-- MarkDown5: double (nullable = true)
 |-- CPI: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Unemployment: double (nullable = true)
```

The dataframe itself has all these duplicate columns, and i'm not sure why.

My code:

```
// Make cutom schema
val schema = StructType(Array(
       StructField("Store", IntegerType, true),
       StructField("Date", DateType, true),
       StructField("IsHoliday", BooleanType, true),
       StructField("Dept", IntegerType, true),
       StructField("Weekly_Sales", IntegerType, true),
       StructField("Temperature", DoubleType, true),
       StructField("Fuel_Price", DoubleType, true),
       StructField("MarkDown1", DoubleType, true),
       StructField("MarkDown2", DoubleType, true),
       StructField("MarkDown3", DoubleType, true),
       StructField("MarkDown4", DoubleType, true),
       StructField("MarkDown5", DoubleType, true),
       StructField("CPI", DoubleType, true),
       StructField("Unemployment", DoubleType, true)))

val dfr = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").schema(schema)
val train_df = dfr.load("/FileStore/tables/train.csv")
val features_df = dfr.load("/FileStore/tables/features.csv")

// Combine the train and features
val data = train_df.join(features_df, Seq("Store", "Date", "IsHoliday"), "left")
data.show(5)
data.printSchema()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working as expected. Your `train_df, features_df` have the same columns  as `schema (14 columns)` after your `load()`.

After your join condition , `Seq("Store", "Date", "IsHoliday")` takes thes 3 columns from the both DFs(total 3+3 =6 columns) and `join` it and gives one set of columns names(3 columns). But rest of columns will be from both `train_df(rest 11 columns), features_df(rest 11 columns).`

Hence you printSchema showing 25 columns(3 + 11 + 11).